# "Die Wellen schlagen hoch"

Tags: phrase

Ist der folgende Satz richtig?

> Immer wenn von Organhandel /*oder welches Thema auch immer*/ die Rede ist, schlagen die Wellen hoch.

Oder wie kann man es besser ausdrücken, dass ein Ereignis für Kontroversen sorgt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Der Satz ist richtig.

B) Was der bessere Ausdruck ist hängt vom Kontext ab, vor allem wie die Kontroversen ablaufen und welchem Milieu die Hörer oder Leser entstammen. Außerdem ist es eine Geschmacksfrage.

> Immer wenn von Organhandel die Rede ist, schlagen die Wellen hoch.

Eine Antwortmöglichkeit bietet die Frage selbst:

> Oder wie kann man es besser ausdrücken, dass ein Ereignis für Kontroversen sorgt?

```
Organhandel sorgt immer für Kontroversen.
```

Andere Möglichkeiten, die aber nicht unbedingt besser sind, wären:

- Organhandel ist ein explosives Thema
- Am Organhandel entzündet sich Streit
- Organhandel führt zu erhitzten Diskussionen
- Organhandel lässt die Öffentlichkeit nicht unberührt (Untertreibung)

Aber der Alternativen sind viele.

Answer (score 1):

Das kann man so sagen, stilistisch in Ordnung und dürfte verstanden werden, ist aber eine individuelle Formulierung.

Die Redewendung lautet:

> [[hohe] Wellen schlagen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Welle#Bedeutung2a)

Auf deinen Fall angewendetes Beispiel:

> Der Organhandel, wann immer davon die Rede ist, schlägt hohe Wellen.

Alternativen:

> - Immer wenn von Organhandel die Rede ist, erregen/erhitzen sich die Gemüter.
> - Der Organhandel, wann immer davon die Rede ist, erregt/erhitzt die Gemüter.
> - Immer wenn von Organhandel die Rede ist, kommt es zu lebhaften Diskussionen.

Ob eine dieser Alternativen besser ist als dein Vorschlag, kann ich nicht sagen, muss ich dem einzelnen Leser überlassen. Jedenfalls werden individuelle Formulierungen im Allgemeinen etwas später verstanden als eingefahrene, zumal dann, wenn wie in deinem Fall das Risiko besteht, dass der Leser das metaphorisch Gemeinte zunächst wörtlich nimmt.

Comment: Ich glaube wirklich nicht, dass sich die "Wellen des Organhandels" dafür interessieren, ob von ihm die Rede ist oder nicht - Du willst deinen ersten Beispielsatz noch einmal überarbeiten, denke ich. So, wie er grade ist, hört er sich ziemlich schräg an.

Comment: @tofro: Woher _du_ schon wieder weißt, was ich will ... Habe die Doppeldeutigkeiten entfernt.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach kann der Organhandel keine hohen Wellen schlagen. Die Diskussion darüber schon eher.

Comment: @tofro: Mit _»Der Organhandel löst große Erregung aus«_ bin ich stilistisch ebenso einverstanden wie mit _»Der Organhandel schlägt hohe Wellen«_, wobei das eine ja das andere bedeutet. Wer es verbietet, verbietet auch: _»Die Gehälter der 1. Fußball-Bundesliga polarisieren.«_

Comment: Das Dumme an der Sache ist, dass "der Organhandel schlägt hohe Wellen" gleichzeitig auch verstanden werden kann als "Der Organhandel nimmt zu und ab". Ein Bild, das man wörtlich verstehen kann, ist kein gutes.

Comment: Unklar ist, was eine individuelle Formulierung sein soll. Hohe Wellen schlagen ist eine typische Phrase, die gerade nicht individuell ist. Zum Streit, ob das Thema oder die Auseinandersetzung darüber die Wellen schlägt: Beides ist möglich. Es ist dann eine Frage der Sachlage, ob der Organhandel selbst die Wellen schlägt, oder nur eine Diskussion darüber, etwa weil sich ein prominenter Autor mit einem Text jetzt dazu äußert.

Comment: @userunknown: Mit individuell meine ich die Formulierung _»schlagen die Wellen hoch«_, was eine selbst erdachte Variation des Standards _»hohe Wellen schlagen«_ ist.

Comment: Das ist eine durch und durch konventionelle Umstellung der Wörter im Deutschen, nicht im mindesten individuell. Google findet 48.100 Treffer für diese individuelle Formulierung.

Comment: @userunknown: _»schlagen die Wellen hoch«_ wird aber metaphorisch gebraucht, alle Fundstellen mit wörtlichem Gebrauch musst du abziehen.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Nein. Die Wortumstellung funktioniert bei Metaphern genauso wie bei der unmittelbaren Bedeutung. "Hoch schlagen die Wellen, wenn ...", "Die Wellen schlagen, wenn vom Organhandel.. , hoch" - das ist alles metaphorisch die gleiche Soße. Mir ist weder ein Fall bekannt, wo eine Metapher nicht umgestellt werden könnte, noch, wo sich aus der Wortstellung ergibt, ob es eine Metapher ist oder nicht. Man müsste also die ganzen Phrasen *addieren*, bei denen nur die Wortstellung eine andere ist.